# Backup & Restore Large Files in Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, ssh, ftp, backup-restoration

Using Windows Server 2008 R2. I am in the process of rebuilding this server, and need to backup the existing D: partition which is currently 2TB (500,000+ files).

I don't need to backup the system drive (C:).

I have tried to FTP these files to a remote PC's external HDD using Filezilla and WinSCP however I have encountered thousands of failed transfers due to file names being too long. Renaming the files isn't an option. I need all the files backed up and restored exactly as the are currently.

I have also tried to copy/paste using the explorer, however the results of this hasn't been great either (a wait time of 42 days IIRC).

What's the best (and preferable quickest) way of be backing up and restoring all of the data currently on the D: partition?

I have FTP and SSH enabled on the server, as well as remote access to it from other (Windows and Linux) computers on the same network.

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Jeebus. Why don't you just use Windows Server Backup and do this the way normal people would do this?

Comment: @joeqwerty because I wasn't aware that existed. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Windows Server Backup to back up the files/disk to an external USB  drive. Then restore them.